# What is the shift parameter doing in R plot function?

Tags: r, plot

While reading [this page](https://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~schluter/R/fit-model/), I saw this code (I generated fake data):

```
y = rbinom(n = 1000,size = 1,prob = .5)
x = abs(rnorm(1000))
mydata = data.frame(x,y)
z <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = mydata, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                      method = "GCV.Cp")
plot(z, se = 1, seWithMean = TRUE, rug = FALSE, shift = mean(predict(z)),
        trans = function(x){exp(x)/(1+exp(x))})  # binomial data
```

What is the role of `shift = mean(predict(z))`?

Comment: Probably take a look at `?plot.gam` or similar method.

Comment: Indeed, it's a `constant to add to each smooth (on the scale of the linear predictor) before plotting. Can be useful for some diagnostics, or with trans`